# Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21] in Google Pay

Tags: angular, transactions, google-pay

I need to test google pay with fake card. But as I insert card details `Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21]` this error occurs. Here is my code in Angular. I am using these fake cards from following[link]https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/sample-tokens

```
paymentRequest: google.payments.api.PaymentDataRequest = {
        apiVersion: 2,
        apiVersionMinor: 0,
        allowedPaymentMethods: [
          {
            type: 'CARD',
            parameters: {
              allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY', 'CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
              allowedCardNetworks: ['AMEX', 'VISA', 'MASTERCARD']
            },
            tokenizationSpecification: {
              type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
              parameters: {
                gateway: 'moneris',
                gatewayMerchantId: 'monca05217',
                
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        merchantInfo: {
          merchantId: '12345678901234567890',
          merchantName: 'Demo Merchant',
        },
        transactionInfo: {
          totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
          totalPriceLabel: 'Total',
          totalPrice: '0.10',
          currencyCode: 'EUR',
          countryCode: 'BE'
        },
        callbackIntents: ['PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION']
      };
    
      onLoadPaymentData = (
        event: Event
      ): void => {
        const eventDetail = event as CustomEvent<google.payments.api.PaymentData>;
        console.log('load payment data', eventDetail.detail);
      }
    
      onPaymentDataAuthorized: google.payments.api.PaymentAuthorizedHandler = (
        paymentData
        ) => {
          console.log('payment authorized', paymentData);
          return {
            transactionState: 'SUCCESS'
          };
        }
    
      onError = (event: ErrorEvent): void => {
        console.error('error', event.error);
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test Google Pay in a sandbox mode. Please try the following

1. Create a new Gmail account for testing purposes
2. Using the newly created Gmail account and join the google groups https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data.
3. All the required test cards will be added to your Gmail account.
4. For the testing of Google Pay, use the newly created Gmail account.

More details can be found here: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite

I am not very sure of your use case but I hope this helps.

Comment: I use this method and after click buy button, Pop up closes and data appear in console. Is transaction completed successfully?

Comment: Does the data have a payment token object?  If so then the card is tokenized and this token can be sent to your API server to initiate the charge request

Comment: Yes it has tokenized object. Thank you for the help. I want to generate receipt using payment data i.e. price. But it doesn't appear in that object

Comment: In order to render the receipt, you should be using the order details from your API server, not from the payment token.  The payment token should be sent to an API server and the API server should initiate the charge and once the charge request is successful on your server then you should generate the required details for your receipt and then hand it over to the client app(angular app)

Comment: Perfect. Can you please tell me how can I call a function from "onPaymentDataAuthorized" this function for API and generate it? Because when I call a function or want to show alert of success. It console objects but google Pay Popup don't close.

Comment: `onPaymentDataAuthorized` expects a promise to be returned ([`Promise<PaymentAuthorizationResult>`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#onPaymentAuthorized))